# Displaying video in small window at corner while allowing user to perform other actions in main window

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

How to implement picture-in-picture mode, first displays a screen which allows user to select a video. On selecting a video, it will start video Activity and play the video in VideoView with an option of allowing user to choose videos. When user click the button, video activity will be shown in PIP mode and user can select video from the previous Activity. On selecting a video again, it will reuse the video activity which is running in PIP mode and start playing new video in full-screen mode.

Below screen shows video activity in fullscreen mode.
[image]

Below screen shows video Activity in PIP mode.[image]

Answer (score 0):

> displaying video in small window at corner while allowing user to perform other actions in main window

It is called [**`picture-in-picture (PIP) mode`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture.html)

Android 8.0 (API level 26) allows activities to launch in picture-in-picture (PIP) mode. PIP is a special type of multi-window mode mostly used for video playback. It lets the user watch a video in a small window pinned to a corner of the screen while navigating between apps or browsing content on the main screen.

**[Steps from docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture.html#continuing_playback)**

> Declaring picture-in-picture support
>
> Switching your activity to picture-in-picture
>
> Handling UI during picture-in-picture
>
> Using a single playback activity for picture-in-picture
>
> Adding controls
>
> Continuing video playback while in picture-in-picture

here is the sample project for [picture-in-picture (PIP) mode](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PictureInPicture/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: i want  displaying video in small window at corner while allowing user to perform other actions in main window  in  Android 6 (API level 23)     displaying video like YouTube